# lunch mean stack application on centos vps Beside apache

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Actually I`m a little confused, please help me.

I learned MEAN stack (AngularJS + Node.js + Express.js + MongoDB) and I made my first application.
I have a centOs vps that have installed Apache + mySQL + PHP and DirectAdmin for manage visually.

My problems are:

1. Which directory of my VPS should I upload my application?
2. How can is install MEAN on this server without disable LAMP? My MEAN application and my WordPress sites work on on VPS.
3. How can I run my MongoDB and Node.js application? By SSH? If I run these by SSH and close my putty, what will happen for my application? Is it necessery to keep open putty all the time?

I want to lunch my app but I`m confused really!

Comment: Actually, this question does not belong to StackOverflow, it's more of a server administration issue. Stiil, short answer would be - you need to set up something like Vagrant if you plan to use it quickly (or to test it). Still, it's not a problem to have LAMP stack app and MEAN app on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand that your MongoDB and NodeJS would run independently without any connection between them.

The status of these would not change once i.e they would not go down once any putty connection is closed. As long as the process associated with them is not killed or goes stale, they would be intact.

Please refer to the below links for further information on installing NodeJS & MongoDB :

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

Please post your folder/file structure of your application and the means chosen for deployment for more help.

Comment: Thanks for your description.